# Redirect all except localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking for a way to do the following redirect (in an .htaccess file):

/something to /something-else

But this should happen for all hosts except for localhost. When any script tries to access /something from localhost (the web-host) then it should not redirect.

I have looked around but have not yet seem what I need in order to do such a special case redirect.

Thanks!!
Johann

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
RewriteRule ^something$ /something-else [L,R]
```